# Is there a way to see all the crates in my project that optionally depend on another crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm adding `parking_lot` to my project and I want my dependencies that can optionally use it to use it as well.

For example, I know that Tokio has a feature flag to enable `parking_lot`, but I want to find all my dependencies that have similar feature flags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yandros on the Rust Discord server whipped up this combination of `cargo metadata` and `jq` to list the crates that have an optional dependency on a given package (`parking_lot` in this example):

```sh
cargo metadata --format-version 1 | jq -c '.packages[] | select(
    .dependencies | any(
        (.name == "parking_lot")
        and
        (.optional == true)
    )
) | .name'
```